# Text wrap formatting error fixing

Tags: python-2.7, word-wrap

I am working in the textwrap module that requires the outputted text to look like [see picture of expected output formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaqbl.png)

However, my output looks like:
[see my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwSth.png)

This is the code I am using for the text wrap:

```
wrap = textwrap.TextWrapper(initial_indent = ' '*4, subsequent_indent = ' '*4)
if name not in bus_name:
    print 'This business is not found'
else:
    count = 0
    for id in bus_name[name]:
        if id not in bus_review:
            print 'No reviews for this business are found'
        else:
            for rev in bus_review[id]:
                print 'Review %d' %(count+1)
                string = textwrap.fill(rev)
                string = string.replace('  ', '$')
                string = wrap.fill(string)
                string = string.replace('$', '\n'+' '*4)
                print '%s' %string
                print 
                count += 1
```